# Layout problems when switch from QWidget to QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt

I'm switching a timeline viewer from QWidget to QGraphicsItem, because QWidget is too heavy, I got performance issues when there are thousand of QWidgets.

I need Layout Management. But I found QGraphicsItem was so light, that it did't support layout. I should use QGraphicsWidget, but there are many useful QGraphicsItem's subclasses, QGraphicsWidget doesn't have them. I think QGraphicsProxyWidget isn't the answer because it is already too slow when I using QWidgets...

So, is there any way to have a layout with any QGraphicsItem? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QGraphicsLayout` and `QGraphicsLayoutItem` are what you are looking for.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicslayout.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicslayoutitem.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have any idea about wrapping a `QGraphicsItem` by using a `QGraphicsLayoutItem`...

Comment: See [Subclassing QGraphicsLayoutItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicslayoutitem.html#subclassing-qgraphicslayoutitem).